# How to depend on jar generated from peer Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, sbt

I have an SBT project (with its attendant build.scala file) that relies on a JAR that is built by another separate Maven project. This JAR is expected to be in the "lib" directory as an unmanaged resource.

Do I want SBT to know where this JAR should be (in the target directory of the Maven project) and copy it over before building?

Or do I want my Maven project to know where the JAR should be copied to (the lib directory of the SBT project) and copy it over on successful build?

Or do I want to tell the maven project to do something with the local repository and have the SBT project reference it as such?

My guess is that the third option is what I want to do. If so, would someone be so kind as to ensure I understand the steps? Specifically, I'm unsure how to properly add the right incantations in my pom.xml to publish the JAR to the local repository and how to reference the local repository in the build.scala file.

I should note that using a remote repository is not an option, as this project must be able to be built on a local development box as well as by our Jenkins build server. If we push the JAR to a remote repository, everyone would be forced to use it, and development versions would collide with checked-in versions. So using the local repository or just copying the JAR into the lib directory is the way to go. That lets developers hack away until they're happy, and when they check in, the Jenkins server picks up the checkin and does its own thing, independent of the state of everyone's (often messy) dev environments).

I just need to figure out the proper way to automate this on builds so that developers don't have to copy the file every time they make a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the maven-managed project to the local maven repository and reference the repository in `resolvers` in sbt.

```
mvn install
```

And then add the following to `build.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"
```

See [Library dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html) in the official documentation of sbt.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I've done and it *almost* works except that future builds aren't causing my cache to reload - but that's a totally separate issue, so this answer is quite correct for the question asked.